# space in object key javascript

Tags: javascript

I didn't know that this is possible in JavaScript:

```
var test = {
    "hello world": function(){
       console.log('test');
    }
};
```

Of course this is only a theoretical question:

Is there a possible way to call the `hello world` function other than `test["hello world"]()`?
Would it be possible to call it with the `.` operator?

Comment: Hope you've recovered from your shocking experience, No, it would not be possible to call the function with `.`.

Comment: This is not a "space in a function name" It's a space in an object key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry but if key is has some special character then you cannot call this with '.' operator.

only way to call is bracket notation which you already know